# C++ Delete Node From Middle of List

Tags: c++, linked-list

For some reason my function to delete a node from the middle of a list is deleting the first node instead of the one specified by the user. Here's my function:

```
template< class NODETYPE >
bool List< NODETYPE >::removeMiddle( NODETYPE &value, int i )
{
    ListNode <NODETYPE> * tempPtr = firstPtr;
    int counter=1;

    if ( isEmpty() )
        return false;
    if (i <= 0)
        return false;

    while (tempPtr != 0 && counter < i){
        counter++;
        if ( firstPtr == lastPtr )
            firstPtr = lastPtr = 0;
        else
            firstPtr = firstPtr->nextPtr;

        if (counter == i){
            value = tempPtr->data;  // data being removed
            delete tempPtr;
        }

    }

    return true;
    RecordCounter--;
}
```

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming it's because this:

```
 if ( firstPtr == lastPtr )
     firstPtr = lastPtr = 0;
 else
     firstPtr = firstPtr->nextPtr;
```

should check and modify `tempPtr`, not `firstPtr`.

Since you don't check by `tempPtr`, your function calls

```
if (counter == i){
   value = tempPtr->data;  // data being removed
   delete tempPtr;
}
```

but `tempPtr` was initially set to `firstPtr` and never modified afterwards.

Of course, you could have easily spotted this by debugging a bit, so I won't correct the code for you, but this is a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed that. I now can iterate correctly through the list, but for some reason my code is not deleting the specific node.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `lastPtr` is for, but the problem is that you are iterating by changing `firstPtr` instead of `tempPtr`.  You then delete `tempPtr`, but that is still pointing to the head of the list.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have assigned `tempPtr = firstPtr` and instead of incrementing `tempPtr`, you are incrementing `firstPtr`.

Check the following code.

```
 while (tempPtr != 0 && counter < i)
    {
             counter++;
             if ( firstPtr == lastPtr)
                 firstPtr = lastPtr = 0;
             else
                 tempPtr = tempPtr->nextPtr; // Here tempPtr should be incremented not firstPtr

             if (counter == i)
             {
                 value = tempPtr->data;  // data being removed
                 delete tempPtr;
             }      
    }
```